# How to use Sonarqube to check Magento 2 modules?

Tags: magento, sonarqube, magento2

I need some guidance on below query related to sonarqube & magento 2:

1. How to install sonarqube?
2. How to validate & generate report for Magento 2 modules using sonarquobe?

I know codeSniffer being used Magento 2. Need suggestion & help on sonarqube magento 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

Hm perhaps that should be asked there : https://magento.stackexchange.com/